# AVAudioPlayer give lazy feedback when preesing sound button

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer, When i pressed button, the sound is playing but its lazy(or giving me late feedback), How can i play sound with rapid feedback..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `prepareToPlay` before trying to play the sound?  As the method suggests this does all the preparation, meaning subsequent calls to `play` should be very quick.

If you need even lower latency, you may need to use AVAudioQueues though.

Comment: Yes i have add it but thax @Tom

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this...

In .h

```
AVAudioPlayer *playerBG
```

In .m

```
AVAudioPlayer *pp = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ting" ofType:@"wav"]] error:nil];
self.playerBG = pp;
[pp prepareToPlay];
[pp release];
```

Comment: Yes i have add it but thax Anish